# How to parse conjunctions in natural language processing?

Tags: natural-language-processing, python, computational-linguistics

Is there an accepted way in NLP to parse conjunctions (and/or) in a sentence?

By following the example below, how would I parse

> I drink orange juice if its the weekend or if it's late and I'm tired.

into

> it's the weekend

and

> it's late

and

> I'm tired

?

Implying an action will be taken when one of the above elements at the 1st level of depth is true.

I know when I hear the sentence that it means "its the weekend" OR ("it's late" AND "I'm tired"), but how could this be determined computationally?

Can an existing python/other library do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems not easy for NLP. I doubt that state-of-the-art NLP tools can reliably determine the correct hierarchical structure of independent clauses. Examples below.

The [Berkeley parser](http://tomato.banatao.berkeley.edu:8080/parser/parser.html) gets it basically right in the sense that it can put `its late` and `I'm tired` on parallel, and they together on parallel with `the weekend`. But still not perfect (`the weekend` should be in the same subtree with `It's` rather than `if its late and I'm tired`)

[image]

The [Stanford parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp), which is available in Python (NLTK), incorrectly parsed `I\'m tired` to the same level of `I drink orange juice`.

[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing your grammar rule for `nltk.RegexpParser()`? I'm still trying to wrap my head around that.

Comment: I didn't use `RegexpParser()`.

Comment: The question and answer both ignore that "its" is a PRP$ (possessive pronoun), while "it's" is required for a  legitimate parse.